# http://ip doesn't work, while https://ip does. What do?

Tags: pi-2, web-server

The title says it all, pretty much.

I've got a basic LAMP set up on my Pi.

My website works flawlessly when I use https:// + ip address.

When I just go to it normally (http:// + ip address) it yields:

```
This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: What is in your Apache config directories - specifically, how is your main website (the https:// + ip website) configured?

Comment: @PhilB.As in what's in httpd.conf in /etc/apache2/conf.d?  
It's just `ServerName localhost`

Comment: If you are using 8080 as the server port, you'll have to use `http://123.456.789:8080` to connect.

Comment: @goldilocks Also didn't work. I'll change ports.

Answer (score 1):

Check if port 80 is blocked. Or, check if your server is even listening to port 80.

`iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` should do it for port 80 inputs.

Answer (score -1):

I changed my portforwarding from 8080 to 80.

I also changed it to port 80 ports.confg

Comment: Ah, so the server was running on 80 but you were forwarding to 8080?  This would explain why `http://123.456.789:8080` did not work.

Comment: I'm confused - is this the solution to the problem? Or is this an update as to what has been done to troubleshoot? If the former - elaborate on the past setup and the new setup, so others can understand what works and didn't work. If the latter - this should be an edit to the question, or at least a comment to the original question.

Comment: Port forwarding on the same host - unless you're using something like SnortInline - is completely useless. It's not a guru-trick nowdays to just add all the IP+Port points to your config